# Multi-Keyspace with Cassandra's Java Driver on fly

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver

Currently, We use Cassandra's Java driver to configure session based on the attributes defined in properties file which looks like this:

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
            .addContactPoints(contactPoints)
            .withPort(environment.getRequiredProperty("cassandra.port", Integer.class))
            .withCredentials(username, password)
            .build();

Session session = cluster.connect(environment.getRequiredProperty("cassandra.keyspace"));
```

What we want to achieve now is to use multi-keyspace on fly, if there is a way to do it, being able to detect the cassandra connection for a given request without changing much on the existing logic except the configuration. Any suggestion or help on this would be a great way to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is to specify table as `keyspace.table` in all queries, and don't rely on the keyspace set in the session.  You can of course have multiple session objects - one per keyspace, but it's not recommended, as every session is quite heavyweight, and open at least 2 connections to every node in the cluster.

Recent versions of the Java driver support setting the keyspace via [`setKeyspace` function of the `SimpleStatement` class](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.5/), but it requires support on the Cassandra side as well (don't remember which version although, at least DSE 6.0 supports this).

(Update): The setting keyspace on query level isn't merged into OSS Java driver, and [available only in DSE Java driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java-dse/1.6/com/datastax/driver/core/SimpleStatement.html#setKeyspace-java.lang.String-).